# Using ActiveRecord Enum in array selections

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base 
  ...
  enum status: [:started, :finished, :failed, :processing]
  ...
end
```

And want to select all processing and finished orders. I cannot write simply

```
@orders = Order.where(status:  [:finished, :processing])
```

because status field is naturally an integer,  not string or literal. So this statement generates

```
2.2.0 :008 > Order.where(status: [:finished, :processing])
   SELECT "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."status" IN (NULL, NULL)
```

Now i do the following

```
@orders = Order.where(status:  [:finished, :processing].map { |s| Order.statuses[s] }
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Try `@orders = Order.where(status:  [1,3])`

Comment: Thank you, but it breaks abstractions. I want to call order statuses by it's names, not integers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you want to call order statuses by it's *names*, the below should work

```
@orders = Order.where(status: Order.statuses[:finished, :processing])
```